# C++ initializing a private variable class into another class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to init my private variable "DressMen black" into class Dialog/QT

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent=0,DressMen b);
    ~Dialog();

    ........



public slots:
    ........



private slots:
  .............

private:

    Ui::Dialog *ui;

    ..........

    DressMen black;


    ..........

};
```

And my DressMen class .h is

```
class DressMen {
public:

    DressMen();
    ~DressMen(void);

    DressMen(std::string name);

    .................
}
```

DressMen.cpp is

```
DressMen::DressMen()
{
    //set values for default constructor
    ..................

}

DressMen::DressMen(std::string name){

    setType(name);

    if(name=="black1"){

            ......

     }

}
```

Now in my Dialog::Dialog I want init my DressMen black1 private variable equal to
- DressMen black("black1");

so I write

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent,DressMen b) : QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Dialog),black(b("black1")) {
.....

}
```

but the compiler error me

```
dialog.h:23: error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of 'Dialog::Dialog(QWidget*, DressMen)'
     explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent=0,DressMen b);
```

I don't understand because I'm in practice for C++ ......

thanks

Comment: If a function has a default argument then it has to have default arguments for all following parameters as well. If you want only one parameter to have a default argument then you need to put it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Brian Bi, you must either specify a default value for `DressMen` or you must make your `DressMen` the first argument.  You could do the following:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent=0, DressMen b = DressMen("black1"));

    ...
};
```

Or you could do this:

```
// Dialog.h
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent=0, DressMen b = DressMen());

    ...
};

// DressMen.h
class DressMen
{
public:
    DressMen(std::string name = "black1");

    ...
};
```

The solution that makes the most sense depends on how you expect `Dialog` and `DressMen` to be used.